# How to align items with "side=BOTTOM"/"anchor=S" properly?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, scrollbar, statusbar, text-widget

I have a GUI app in which i have a BOTTOM scrollbar and a BOTTOM status bar, both at the bottom. I want to align them in such a way that scrollbar comes above the status bar at bottom like this ( in official notepad ) :
[image]

> Here statusbar is at bottom and scrollbar is at top.

However what i made is :
[image]

> Here statusbar is at top and scrollbar is at bottom.

*I also tried anchor=S but that also didn't worked and throwed the same result.*

**CODE : ( Status Bar )**

```
    statusbar = Frame(textarea)
    statusbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
    statusbar_Content1 = Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, width=18, text="Ln 1, col 1")
    statusbar_Content2 = Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, text="100%")
    statusbar_Content3 = Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, width=15, text="Windows (CRLF)")
    statusbar_Content4 = Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, width=13, text="UTF-8")
    statusbar_Content4.pack(side=RIGHT)
    Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, text="|", state=DISABLED).pack(side=RIGHT)
    statusbar_Content3.pack(side=RIGHT)
    Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, text="|", state=DISABLED).pack(side=RIGHT)
    statusbar_Content2.pack(side=RIGHT)
    Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, text="|", state=DISABLED).pack(side=RIGHT)
    statusbar_Content1.pack(side=RIGHT)
    Label(statusbar, anchor=SW, text="|", state=DISABLED).pack(side=RIGHT)
```

**CODE : ( Scroll Bar )**

```
Scroll2 = Scrollbar(root, orient=HORIZONTAL)
Scroll2.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
Scroll2.config(command=textarea.xview)
```

**CODE : ( Scrollbar is bound with Text widget )**

```
textarea = Text(root, font=fontsmain, yscrollcommand=Scroll.set,xscrollcommand=Scroll2.set, undo=True)
textarea.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)
```

**CONCLUSION :**

> ***Is there any way of setting these such that SCROLLBAR come above STATUSBAR and vise versa ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pack` works by placing a widget on one side of unallocated space. That means that the results are dependent on the order that widgets are packed. This is called the *stacking order*.

For example, if you pack the scrollbar first, it will be placed at the very bottom of the window since no space has yet been allocated to anything. When you later call `pack` on the statusbar, the very bottom of the window has already been allocated so it will be placed at the bottom of the free space above the scrollbar.

Knowing this, when you change the order in which you call `pack`, you change the order in which the widgets appear in the window. So, a simple solution is to make sure you pack the statusbar before you pack the scrollbar.

`pack` also has options that let you specify whether a widget is before or after some other widget in the ordering. For example, you can pack the scrollbar and then pack the statusbar but tell it to appear before the scrollbar in the stacking order. When you are using `side='bottom'`, that will result in the statusbar appearing below the scrollbar.

Notice the difference between the following three examples:

```
statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

[image: screenshot, statusbar first]

```
scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
```

[image: screenshot, scrollbar first]

```
scrollbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x", before=scrollbar)
```

[image: screenshot, using the "before" option]

Comment: Your code is correct _BUT_ Its not working for my code, no matter which widget i pack first, when scrollbar comes in it takes the bottom, no matter it is packed at top of the code or bottom, dont know why ?

Comment: @AaYanYasin: it's because your code isn't packing things in the correct order. `pack` is working as designed in your case. This is why you are responsible for creating a [mcve] that accurately reflects your problem.  You didn't do that, so we have to guess at the missing pieces.